# Change default exchangeType as fanout through Spring cloud stream or rabbitmq server config

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-cloud-stream

I have two microservices Student and Teacher

in Student microservice I have created MessageSink for exchange XYZ

```
@Input("XYZ")
SubscribableChannel xyz();
```

and in Teacher microservice I have configured exchange XYZ as a fanout

application.properties

```
 spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.XYZ.producer.exchangeType=fanout
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.XYZ.contentType=application/json
```

But problem I am facing here is Student service is starting before Teacher service and it is creating XYZ exchange with type Topic.

To tackle this I have added exchangeType in both the services (i.e consumer as well as producer). As services are growing in numbers, these configurations are growing in numbers.

I want to change the default exchangeType as fanout, so following are few questions.

1. is there any way to change default `exchangeType` as fanout instead of topic in `spring-cloud-stream`?
2. Is there any way to change default `exchangeType` through rabbit-mq configuration?
3. As a work around I planning to keep `exchangeType` as `topic` and routing key `#`. But the problem with this approach is `stomp` client is creating queue for every browser host with queue name as `stomp-subscription-randomString` and blank routing key. So is there any way to provide routing key while subscribing to stream? I am using `/exchange/exchangeName` as exchange `URL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some documentation on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options_4

You may consider to play with this option:

> exchangeType
>
> The exchange type: `direct`, `fanout` or `topic` for non-partitioned destinations and direct or topic for partitioned destinations.
>
> Default: topic.

Therefore it will look in our config like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.XYZ.consumer.exchangeType=fanout
```

There are some other options, like: `declareExchange=false` and `bindingRoutingKey` to consider as well.

Comment: you didn't read description. Issue is configuring it multiple services. I have multiple consumers and any of them can start before other, so I want to change default exchangeType in order minimize configuration s

Comment: That somehow collides with you ask in the question... Anyway: you always can turn off exchange declaration using `declareExchange=false`. Right, in this case you can just configure it on the RabbitMQ Broker and existing entity will be used in your application(s).

Comment: is it possible to use pattern in it for eg. `bindings.*.consumer.declareExchange=false`

Comment: If you mean some *global* configuration option to avoid duplication for each target, then no, I'm not aware of that possibility.